# Jboss Secure web service error by using the database login module: EJB Invocation failed

Tags: java, security, ejb, jboss7.x

I've a little problem with my Jboss AS 7.1.1.Final Web Service authorization. I want to secure the web service via the database login module.

Everything works properly when the service is running without an authorization. I've implemented a jax-ws based standalone client to call and access the web service.
The login information are currently saved without an encryption.

**Server:**

standalone-full.xml:

I've created a security-domain with a Database login-module and a security-realm in the file standalone-full.xml like this:

```
<security-domain name="sensor" cache-type="default">  
     <authentication>  
          <login-module code="Database" flag="required">  
               <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/HomeServer"/>  
               <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd from users where login=?"/>  
               <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role,'Roles' from user_roles where login=?"/>  
          </login-module>  
     </authentication>  
</security-domain>   

<management>
    <security-realms>            
        <security-realm name="SensorRealm">
            <authentication>
                <jaas name="sensor"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
</management>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
    <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="SensorRealm"/>
</subsystem>
```

**LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface.java:**

```
package server.interfaces.sensor;  

import javax.ejb.Remote;  
import javax.jws.WebResult;  
import javax.jws.WebService;  

@WebService  
@Remote  
public interface LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface {  

@WebResult(name = "lightBarrierEvent")  
    public void lightBarrierEvent();  
}
```

**LightBarrierSensorService.java:**

```
package server.webservice.sensor;  

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;  
import javax.ejb.Stateless;  
import javax.jws.WebService;  

import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain;  
import org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.WebContext;  

import server.interfaces.sensor.LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface;  

@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "server.interfaces.sensor.LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface")
@WebContext(authMethod = "BASIC", secureWSDLAccess = false)  
@SecurityDomain(value = "sensor")  
@RolesAllowed(value = {"lightBarrier"})  
public class LightBarrierSensorService implements LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface {  

     @Override  
     public void lightBarrierEvent() {  
          System.out.println("CALLED");  
     }  
}
```

**Client:**

**Client.java:**

```
package client;  

import client.helper.LightBarrierSensorHelper;  

public class Client {  

     public static void main(String[] args) {  
          LightBarrierSensorHelper.getInstance().push();  
     }  
}
```

**LightBarrierSensorHelper.java:**

```
package client.helper;  

import java.net.URL;  

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;  
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;  
import javax.xml.ws.Service;  

import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;  

import server.interfaces.sensor.LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface;  

public class LightBarrierSensorHelper {  

     private static final LightBarrierSensorHelper instance = new LightBarrierSensorHelper();  

     private LightBarrierSensorHelper(){  
     }  

     public static LightBarrierSensorHelper getInstance(){  
          return instance;  
     }  

     public void push(){  
          try {  
               URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/HomeServerServer-0.0.1/LightBarrierSensorService?wsdl");  
               QName qName = new QName("http://sensor.webservice.server/", "LightBarrierSensorServiceService");  

               Service service = Service.create(url, qName);  
               LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface lb = service.getPort(LightBarrierSensorServiceInterface.class);  

               BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) lb;  
               bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");  
               bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "test");  

               lb.lightBarrierEvent();  
          } catch (Exception e) {  
               System.err.println(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));  
          }  
     }  
}
```

**Error:**

Now, when I run my client, I get the following error:

```
    javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public void server.webservice.sensor.LightBarrierSensorService.lightBarrierEvent() of bean: LightBarrierSensorService is not allowed  
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)  
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)  
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)  
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)  
     at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)  
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.lightBarrierEvent(Unknown Source)  
     at client.helper.LightBarrierSensorHelper.push(LightBarrierSensorHelper.java:36)  
     at client.Client.main(Client.java:8)
```

The following shows the error on the server:

```
    14:13:16,776 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-127.0.0.1-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component LightBarrierSensorService for method public void server.webservice.sensor.LightBarrierSensorService.lightBarrierEvent(): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public void server.webservice.sensor.LightBarrierSensorService.lightBarrierEvent() of bean: LightBarrierSensorService is not allowed  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.java:112)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)  
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)  
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)  
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)  
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)  
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  

14:13:16,811 ERROR [org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3] (http-127.0.0.1-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Method invocation failed with exception: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public void server.webservice.sensor.LightBarrierSensorService.lightBarrierEvent() of bean: LightBarrierSensorService is not allowed: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public void server.webservice.sensor.LightBarrierSensorService.lightBarrierEvent() of bean: LightBarrierSensorService is not allowed  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.java:112)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)  
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)  
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)  
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)  
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)  
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  

14:13:16,846 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-127.0.0.1-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Application {http://sensor.webservice.server/}LightBarrierSensorServiceService#{http://sensor.interfaces.server/}lightBarrierEvent has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public void server.webservice.sensor.LightBarrierSensorService.lightBarrierEvent() of bean: LightBarrierSensorService is not allowed  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.createFault(JBossWSInvoker.java:246)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:207)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)  
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)  
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)  
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)  
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)  
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)  
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]  
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public void server.webservice.sensor.LightBarrierSensorService.lightBarrierEvent() of bean: LightBarrierSensorService is not allowed  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]  
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerEJB.java:112)  
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)  
    ... 32 more
```

Can someone help me to solve this Problem?

Thanks in advance and i hope to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
The reason was I used a wrong dependency in my maven configuration, consequently the import for the @WebContext was wrong.
For Jboss 7.1.Final Web Services you should use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>jbossws-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax</groupId> 
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId> 
    <version>6.0</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

And the import have to be changed from

> import org.jboss.wsf.spi.annotation.WebContext

to

> import org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext

.

With kind regards.